# Generic classes using a ViewHolder in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, templates, generics

I want to be able to return a certain instance of one of my child holders (Base is GameHolder). I'm having trouble doing this, here is what I have:

```
@Override
public GameHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(mHolderMap.get(viewType).getLayoutResID(), parent, false);

    //I'm trying to avoid using this switch by using a HashMap because it is going to continue growing as I add more leagues.
    /*switch(viewType)
    {
        case -1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_item, parent, false);
            return new HeaderGameHolder(view, getActivity());
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_nba_game_item, parent, false);
            return new NBAGameHolder(view, getActivity());
        case 2:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mlb_game_item, parent, false);
            return new MLBGameHolder(view, getActivity());
        default:
            return null;
    }*/

    //this is where I'm having trouble, I don't know how to return the correct type.
    Class<? extends GameHolder> myClass = mHolderMap.get(viewType).getHolderClass();
    return new myClass(view, getActivity());
}
```

Here is my HashMap and its setup method:

```
private HashMap<Integer, ViewMapHelper> mHolderMap = new HashMap<>();
private void setupGameHolderMap()
{
    mHolderMap.put(LeagueInfo.headerID, new ViewMapHelper(R.layout.list_header_item, HeaderGameHolder.class));
    mHolderMap.put(LeagueInfo.nbaID, new ViewMapHelper(R.layout.list_nba_game_item, NBAGameHolder.class));
    mHolderMap.put(LeagueInfo.mlbID, new ViewMapHelper(R.layout.list_mlb_game_item, MLBGameHolder.class));
}
```

Here is my ViewMapHelper class:

```
private class ViewMapHelper
{
    int mLayoutResID;
    Class<? extends GameHolder> mHolderClass;

    public ViewMapHelper(int layoutResID, Class<? extends GameHolder> holderClass)
    {
        mLayoutResID = layoutResID;
        mHolderClass = holderClass;
    }

    public int getLayoutResID()
    {
        return mLayoutResID;
    }

    public Class<? extends GameHolder> getHolderClass()
    {
        return mHolderClass;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the first block of code, my problem is here. The second line does not work:

```
Class<? extends GameHolder> myClass = mHolderMap.get(viewType).getHolderClass();
return new myClass(view, getActivity());
```

I want to be able to return the holder type that corresponds to the class saved in the hash map. I'm new to using Java's generics and template classes so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to find the constructor and invoke it.

```
Constructor[] ctors = myClass.getDeclaredConstructors();
Constructor ctor = null;
for (int i = 0; i < ctors.length; i++) {
    if (ctor.getGenericParameterTypes().length == 2) {
         ctor = ctors[i];
         break;
    }
}
if (ctor != null) {
     return ctor.newInstance(view, getActivity());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After quite some time working on this I was able to solve the problem. So hopefully it helps someone else who is using mulitple viewtypes in their RecyclerView and wants to quickly create their ViewHolders without using a long switch or if/else if statements.

I first made an interface:

```
interface GameHolderInterface
{
    GameHolder getNewGameHolder(View itemView);
}
```

Then I modified my `ViewMapHelper` class to use the interface:

```
private class ViewMapHelper
{
    int mLayoutResID;
    GameHolderInterface mGameIntObj;

    public ViewMapHelper(int layoutResID, GameHolderInterface gameIntObject)
    {
        mLayoutResID = layoutResID;
        mGameIntObj = gameIntObject;
    }

    public int getLayoutResID()
    {
        return mLayoutResID;
    }

    public GameHolderInterface getGameHolderInt()
    {
        return mGameIntObj;
    }
}
```

Then I modified the setup for the the `HashMap` (mHolderMap):

```
private void setupGameHolderMap()
{
    mHolderMap.put(LeagueInfo.headerID, new ViewMapHelper(R.layout.list_header_item, new GameHolderInterface() {
        @Override
        public GameHolder getNewGameHolder(View itemView)
        {
            return new HeaderGameHolder(itemView, mMainActivity);
        }
    }));

    mHolderMap.put(LeagueInfo.nbaID, new ViewMapHelper(R.layout.list_nba_game_item, new GameHolderInterface() {
        @Override
        public GameHolder getNewGameHolder(View itemView)
        {
            return new NBAGameHolder(itemView, mMainActivity);
        }
    }));

    mHolderMap.put(LeagueInfo.mlbID, new ViewMapHelper(R.layout.list_mlb_game_item, new GameHolderInterface() {
        @Override
        public GameHolder getNewGameHolder(View itemView)
        {
            return new MLBGameHolder(itemView, mMainActivity);
        }
    }));
}
```

And then in `onCreateViewHolder()` I now have:

```
@Override
public GameHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    ViewMapHelper vmh = mHolderMap.get(viewType);
    View view = inflater.inflate(vmh.getLayoutResID(), parent, false);

    return vmh.getGameHolderInt().getNewGameHolder(view);
}
```

So the key was to use an interface and then make it a member in my ViewMapHelper class so I can then call `getNewGameHolder()` to access a specific type of GameHolder.